# Getting "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" even though I only have one res.render()

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using Mongoose and Express/Node.js to build a simple api, but when I try to click on the "Read More" link (which uses Express routing parameters), I get "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".  I understand that this happens when multiple responses are sent for a single post, but I can't for the life of me find where this is happening.

My code is below:

````
  Post.find({}, function(err, foundPosts) {
    res.render("home", {homeStartingContent: homeStartingContent, posts: foundPosts});
    res.redirect("/");
  });


})

app.get("/compose", function(req, res) {
  res.render("compose");
})

app.post("/compose", function(req, res) {
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    body: req.body.newPost,
    teaser: req.body.newPost.substring(0,99) + "...",
  });

  // save the post and refresh home page to display most recent post
  post.save(function(err) {
    if(!err) {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});

// express routing parameters; uses whatever comes after : to decide what to do
app.get("/posts/:postId", function(req, res) {
  const requested = _.lowerCase(req.params.postId);
  Posts.findOne({_id: requested}, function(err, post) {
    res.render("post", {post: post});
  });
});```

I'm pretty sure the issue is in the last app.get("/posts/:postID"...), but I can't figure it out.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that this happens when multiple responses are sent for a single post

It also happens when you send more headers after already having sent a response. And that's what you do by calling first `res.render` and then `res.redirect` near the top of your code snippet. Also, this does not make sense, because the `redirect`ion will prevent the user from reading what you `render`ed before.

Comment: That took care of it, thank you!  I thought redirect would just reload the page, I didn't realize it was sending it again.  Thank you!